# Keras and OpenCV (CV2) as dependencies for Python executable?

Tags: python, keras, pyinstaller, opencv

For a school assignment, I have written a system (in Python 3, on Windows 8.1) that takes in a specific scanned form, recognizes digits, compares it to an answer key, and puts the 'grades' into a csv. I have the system working completely based on individual files now (e.g. I have one file that 'parses' the scanned document, one part that does the recognition, a file that trained the neural net used to recognize, etc) but my instructor is requiring that I turn it into an executable.

I learned about pyinstaller recently, and I feel like this does what I want, but I am lost on how dependencies are supposed to work here. I believe I should create a 'run script' in Python that imports the individual components and calls functions with arguments in a specified order. I also have a 'template' image that needs to be stored with the executable.

For Keras and CV2, in particular, I know there are a very large number of dependencies. Do all of these dependencies need to be present in the directory that I install my program or does pyinstaller take them from the pip directory in which they are installed? For OpenCV, do I have to figure out how to manage to bring that into the installer as well?

Apologies if this isn't the correct place to ask the question.

Answer (score 1):

Pyinstaller uses [hooks](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/hooks.html) for each package, you would need to check to ensure that Pyinstaller is compatible with your Keras and OpenCV packages. Most packages will work out of the box  and you can check [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/wiki/Supported-Packages) for third-party supported packages. I currently use OpenCV v4.0.0 and Pyinstaller v3.4 which works well. From my understanding, Pyinstaller takes them from the pip directory where they are installed so you shouldn't need to worry about having the dependencies present in the same directory. Any packages used in your program will be automatically included in the Pyinstaller executable depending on what flags that you use to build the program.

You can use the `--onefile` flag for a single file bundled executable. Another useful flag is the `--windowed` flag which allows you to debug the program from the command line. You can find more information on flags [here](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/usage.html).